# Recursions where one definition depends on another. How to Block or have local variables?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, difference-equations

I have been using Mathematica to solve a second order differential equation using the second order Verlet method. My code looks like:

```
x[0]=x0;
y[0]=y0;
vx[0]=vx0;
vy[0]=vy0;

x[n_] := x[n] = x[n - 1] + h (vx[n - 1] - h/2 (x[n - 1]/((x[n - 1])^2 + (y[n - 1])^2)^(3/2)))
y[n_] := y[n] = y[n - 1] + h (vy[n - 1] - h/2 (y[n - 1]/((y[n - 1])^2 + (y[n - 1])^2)^(3/2)))
vx[n_] := vx[n] = vx[n - 1] - h/2 (x[n - 1]/(x[n - 1]^2 + y[n - 1]^2)^(3/2) + x[n]/(x[n]^2 + y[n]^2)^(3/2))
vy[n_] := vy[n] = vy[n - 1] - h/2 (y[n - 1]/(x[n - 1]^2 + y[n - 1]^2)^(3/2) + x[n]/(x[n]^2 + y[n])^(3/2))
```

I tried using Table but x[2] cannot be evaluated until vx[1] is evaluated. Does someone have a direction as to which function would store the local variables for later use?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. This setup should work fine (although I recommend using numbers in place of the initial conditions, because the expressions will get very large very quickly). If you're interested in what, say, `x` does, just do `Scan[x, Range[0, 3]]`. This will automatically evaluate and set the values of `x[0]` through `x[3]` and will do the same for whatever quantities those values depend on. You can see that by evaluating `?x` afterward.

Comment: x[2] evaluated fine for me. The result is ugly, but Mathematica will calculate it.